# Causing ORA errors in a program using JDBC. How can I find what's causing them?

Tags: oracle, java, jdbc

So I'm building a java app to interface with the company's database. Whenever it causes an ORA error, it just prints something like the following to system output:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Is there some way I can see what's causing it? Maybe some SQL statement I can use to see the last 10 errors caused on a table or something? I have SQLDeveloper if that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Either set tracing on client(jdbc) side. Or you can create system trigger `ON SYSTEMERROR` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536516/how-to-develop-an-after-serverror-trigger-in-oracle), but this requires DBA privs.

Comment: `SYSTEMERROR` trigger won't help (as it didn't work in the post you are referring ). In order to appear in  v$sql the query must be validated. Queries with syntax errors never get successfully parsed

Comment: @a1ex07 it won't apper in the v$sql view, but it should be read from ora_sql_txt function. It is the attribute passed to even trigger.

Comment: yeah you're right , I didn't scroll down to the answer that mentioned `sql_txt` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable trace for you session after application is connected, for example,  `EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(binds=>TRUE);`, then you will find the culprit in trace file.  More information about tracing in Oracle https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof